# Select all images without a specific parent class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to select the second image inside of a div (.entry-content) unless the image has a specific parent class. Here is an example of my attempts

In the example below, I would need to select the third image since the second image has the parent class of parent-div.

```js
jQuery(".entry-content").each(function() {
  jQuery(this).find("img:eq(1):not(:parent.parent-div)").addClass("second-img");
});
// or 
jQuery(".entry-content").each(function() {
  jQuery(this).find("img:eq(1)").not().parent(".parent-div").addClass("second-img");
});
```

```css
.second-img { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="entry-content">
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p><img /></p>
  <div class="parent-div"><img /></div>
  <div><img /></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="parent-div"><img /></div>
  <p></p>
  <img />
  <img />
  <p></p>
  <p><img /></p>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please make it a [mcve] with images from placeholder.com or similar

Answer (score 0):

you can use below script to find the correct image element.
You can use `filter` to filter image element not having parent-div class for parent. See below script for reference

```js
$(function() {
  var found = false;
  var $img = $('div.entry-content img:gt(1)').filter(function() {
    if (!found) {
      var $parent = $(this).parent();
      if(!$parent.hasClass('parent-div')) {
        found = true;
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  });
  $img.each(function() {
    console.log($(this).attr('src'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="entry-content">
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p><img src="1" /></p>
  <div class="parent-div"><img src="2" /></div>
  <div><img src="3" /></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="parent-div"><img src="4" /></div>
  <p></p>
  <img src="5" />
  <img src="6" />
  <p></p>
  <p><img src="7" /></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single selector to find all images except those that have .parent-div:

As some of your images aren't in a wrapper and some are in `p` or `div` it needs two parts:

```
.entry-content > img
.entry-content > *:not(.parent-div) > img
```

The `>` ensures the images aren't included twice

Then `.eq(1)` (zero-based) gets the "second".

```js
$(".entry-content > img,.entry-content > *:not(.parent-div) > img").eq(1).addClass("second-img");
```

```css
.second-img {
  border: 20px solid green;
}

.parent-div>img {
  border: 5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="entry-content">
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bI1Y.jpg" height="50" /></p>
  <div class="parent-div"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bI1Y.jpg" height="50" /></div>
  <div><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bI1Y.jpg" height="50" /></div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="parent-div"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bI1Y.jpg" height="50" /></div>
  <p></p>
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bI1Y.jpg" height="50" />
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bI1Y.jpg" height="50" />
  <p></p>
  <p><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bI1Y.jpg" height="50" /></p>
</div>
```